# Merge 2 audio recordings using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, audio, merge, ubuntu-14.04, mediarecorder

I am creating an **Android Audio Recorder** app..
I am implementing **Record and Pause** feature in it..

**This is my code :**

```
private void mergeFile(File combineFile, File output){
       File[] listofFiles=MaverickDir.listFiles();
       FileInputStream fisToFinal = null;
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       try {
           fos = new FileOutputStream(combineFile);
           fisToFinal = new FileInputStream(combineFile);
           for(int i=0;i<listofFiles.length;i++){
               if(!listofFiles[i].exists())
                   continue;
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(listofFiles[i]);
               SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fisToFinal, fileInputStream);
               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
               try {
                   for (int readNum; (readNum = fileInputStream.read(buf)) != -1;)
                       fos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
               } 
               finally {
                   if(fileInputStream!=null){
                       fileInputStream.close();
                   }
                   if(sis!=null){
                       sis.close();
                   }
               }
           }
       } 
       catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally{
           try {
               if(fos!=null){
                   fos.flush();
                   fos.close();
               }
               if(fisToFinal!=null){
                   fisToFinal.close();
               }
           } 
           catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
```

This code is not helping me in merging all the **recorded-paused, again recorded-paused, and again recorded-paused** audio recordings..

I just get a file with total length of the recording, with just the initial piece of recorded audio (till you press pause for the first time)..

The Merging is not happening here..
What shall I do to resolve it...??

**Please help..**

Answer (score 0):

In This scene,you should record audio frame by frame.

I have recorded video in a app like this.

So I recommend you to use this library : [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).